# Java dynamic binding and method overriding process

Tags: java, object, inheritance, reference, dynamic-binding

I kind of know the principle that static binding happens at compile time while dynamic binding happens at run time. I have read through several related questions. I could follow the train of thought of many of them, but I messed up and lost my logic again when it comes to me with specific question like below:

```
class Cake {
    public void taste (Cake c) {
        System.out.println("In taste of Cake class");
    }
}

class ChocolateCake extends Cake {
    public void taste(Cake c) {
        System.out.println("In taste (Cake version) of ChocolateCake class");
    }
    public void taste(ChocolateCake cc) {
        System.out.println("In taste (ChocolateCake version) of ChocolateCake class");
    }
}

class BirthdayCake extends ChocolateCake {
    public void taste(Cake c) {
        System.out.println("In taste (Cake version) of BirthdayCake class");
    }
    public void taste (ChocolateCake cc) {
        System.out.println("In taste (ChocolateCake version) of BirthdayCake class");
    }
    public void taste(BirthdayCake bc) {
        System.out.println("In taste (BirthdayCake version) of BirthdayCake class");
    }
}
```

The following objects have been created:

```
Cake c1 = new Cake();
ChocolateCake cc = new ChocolateCake();
Cake c2 = new ChocolateCake();
Cake c3 = new BirthdayCake();
```

Output are shown below:

```
c1.taste(cc);//Output: In taste of Cake class
cc.taste(cc);//Output: In taste (ChocolateCake version) of ChocolateCake class
c2.taste(cc);//Output: In taste (Cake version) of ChocolateCake class
((BirthdayCake) c3).taste(cc);//Output: In taste (ChocolateCake version) of BirthdayCake class
((BirthdayCake) c3).taste((BirthdayCake) c3);//Output: In taste (BirthdayCake  version) of BirthdayCake class
```

Basically, my question is why `c2.taste(cc)` invoke `taste(Cake c)`method in class `ChocolateCake`?

Here is my thought:
`c2`'s static type is `Cake` which decide that a method in `Cake` is gonna to be called. When it comes to the run-time, the dynamic type of c2, namely `ChocolateCake`, decide a method in `ChocolateCake` cake will be invoked. And as its parameter's type is `ChocolateCake` decided the `taste(ChocolateCake cc)` will finally be called.

Apparently, this thought is wrong. And if I suppose the signature of the method was settled down at compile-time as the static type of `c2` is `Cake` and there is only one method in class `Cake`. When it comes to run-time, it will call the override method in class `ChocolateCake`  The whole thing would kind of make sense. My confusion is that why it works like this way but not the former way?

Another thing I don't understand is that we are not allow to write a statement like below as it would get a compile error:

`ChocolateCake cc = new Cake();`.

But why it is possible for ChocolateCake type reference finally to pass a Cake object, as it should call the `taste(Cake c)` method in class `ChocolateCake` to get correct output as above.

I think I still do not understand the whole process of calling a method on an object reference. Like what happen when deciding best-matching method at compile-time and what happen after that, let's say, run-time (I am not sure is there any other phase in this process).

Can anyone help illustrate this process?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The issue is with parameter binding not being dynamic. The parameter will still be `Cake` at runtime as it was bound to `Cake.cake(Cake c)` at compile-time, but the method call (being dynamic) will end up being `ChocolateCake.cake(Cake c)`. There's probably a good duplicate for this question, let's see if I can find one.

Comment: Thanks, your answer pretty much solved my question. But I am still confused with the parameter passing thing as I mentioned in last few parts. Namely, why is it possible for `ChocolateCake` type reference finally passing a `Cake` object while statement like `ChocolateCake cc = new Cake();` is even not allowed?

Comment: That's just basic inheritance. All cakes are `Cakes`, but a `Cake` is not a `ChocolateCake` (it could be, but that's not definitive). You wouldn't write `Woman w = new Human();`, because that's not necessarily true either.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to simplify the example and go through the steps. I've also added @Override for clarity.

```
class Cake {
    public void taste (Cake c) {
        System.out.println("In taste of Cake class");
    }
}

class ChocolateCake extends Cake {
    @Override
    public void taste(Cake c) {
        System.out.println("In taste (Cake version) of ChocolateCake class");
    }
    public void taste(ChocolateCake cc) {
        System.out.println("In taste (ChocolateCake version) of ChocolateCake class");
    }
}

ChocolateCake param = new ChocolateCake();    
Cake cake = new ChocolateCake();
cake.taste(param);
```

When you call `cake.taste(param);` the java compiler chooses compile time which method will be callled, based on the type of the reference, not the actual object type the reference is pointing to.

The reference type of `cake` is `Cake`, so the compiler looks in the base class `Cake` for a method that is called `taste` and accepts `Cake` as parameter. Since `ChocolateCake` is `Cake` (through inheritance) the compiler finds a match.

Because essentially you have an override of the base `taste` method, during runtime and due to dynamic dispatch, the JVM resolves the actual type of the `cake` reference, which is `ChocolateType` and invokes the override of the already chosen method.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried out using the following main():

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ChocolateCake cc = new ChocolateCake();
        Cake c = new ChocolateCake();
        Cake c1 = new Cake();
        Cake c2 = new ChocolateCake();
        Cake c3 = new BirthdayCake();

        ChocolateCake c4 = new BirthdayCake();

        c1.taste(cc);
        c1.taste(c);

        c2.taste(cc);
        c2.taste(c);

        c3.taste(cc);
        c3.taste(c);

        c4.taste(cc);
        c4.taste(c);

    }
```

the output is like this:

```
In taste of Cake class
In taste of Cake class
In taste (Cake version) of ChocolateCake class
In taste (Cake version) of ChocolateCake class
In taste (Cake version) of BirthdayCake class
In taste (Cake version) of BirthdayCake class
In taste (ChocolateCake version) of BirthdayCake class
In taste (Cake version) of BirthdayCake class
```

so far, my understanding is like the following:

1. which class to look for the method, depends on the object actual type (you may use dynamic binding)
2. in that target class, which method to be called, in this case, depends both on the reference type of the object(which call the method) and the reference type of that parameter. we pick the more general one (reference type) from the two, and interpret the method called.

e.g.

```
c4.taste(cc);//c4:ChocolateCake cc:ChocolateCake -> ChocolateCake version
c4.taste(c);//c4:ChocolateCake c:Cake -> Cake version
```

just some own understanding, also very new to java;)